# Where to insert code that creates buttons programmatically?

Tags: iphone, button

I receive some JSON from the net and based on that data, I must create 2 or 3 buttons. Part of my gui is static and created in NIB (won't change), only the number of buttons will change. I found this code for making buttons in code:

```
 //create the button
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

 //set the position of the button
 button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);
 //set the button's title
 [button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is this the right way? In which method of my viewcontroller should I put this code?

Comment: You can create the button anytime you choose.  Just add it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the button whenever you want, as long as the view has been loaded already. The one thing you'd need to add to the above code is

```
[[self view] addSubview:button];
```

Using this code, you have a button on the screen, but it won't be able to trigger any actions. You'll probably also want to add:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Just wondering, what if i make a mistake and put my button to the same position that some other UI element from NIB occupies. Will the overlap or will everything crash?

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, the UI element added _last_ will be displayed on top (painter's method), and tapping will activate whichever UI element is on top. Nothing will crash due to this alone.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the buttons in the delegate/method that parses the JSON data. 
Don't forget to add the created buttons to your view:

```
[containerView addSubview:button];
```